# Car will not start & interior lights flicker whenever I try. No noise whenever I turn the key

Tags: starting, hyundai, battery-drain

2007 Hyundai Entourage

Car will not start & interior lights flicker whenever I try.  No noise whenever I turn the key.  Took several attempts to jump it yesterday, but finally did start.  Today I'm back to square one. What is going on?  I just had the alternator replaced 2 months ago.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check the battery voltage when you first shut it off after a good long run, then again in the morning after it's set for a while. If there's a big difference, pull the battery cable over night and see if it still drops voltage. If it does, you need a new battery. It should be around 12.5-13.2vdc after it's been sitting for a period of time. If it won't hold the charge, you need a new battery.

Comment: If the battery is bad change it ASAP. A bad battery can destroy a new alternator. You should also have a parasitic draw test done.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

2007? Check engine to body grounds for corrosion. Check battery and clean terminal posts. Go over the alternator, a tech may have not done a thorough job or used a poor quality remanufactured one.

Also look for an aftermarket alarm or other battery or fuse box hack that is causing a drain.

Finally be prepared to replace the battery if it is old or fails a load test.

This is basic stuff. Battery is likely, but expensive, so change it last after going over electrical paths. It's a lot to look at but be persistent, your labor is free.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be linked to the battery in this case. It could have been a problem with the electricals/wires as well, but just because you said you could jump start the car after several attempts, it rules out the possibility of any faulty wires.
You also mentioned that you had the alternator replaced 2 months ago. It can be a possibility that the alternator is not properly connected to the battery and is not charging it. The battery lasted for a while on it's initial charge and now the alternator is not able to keep up or is not charging the battery at all. 
I dont see any other reason why your car will not start.

Comment: generally if the alternator cannot charge the battery then the car would not run for two months while ruling out the chances of wiring becoming loose after a month

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% low battery!
Why your battery is low is different question you should check your car if it's charging when you start it. Easiest way (not the safest) to test if your alternator is charging is to disconnect one side of the battery if the car stalls(dies/shut off) your alternator isn't charging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure there is no cd stuck in the radio,as this could run the battery down ,I had this to happen and pulled the fuse to the radio to confirm this was the problem, battery quit draining, car would start normally